# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer ( unable to access the remote server for restarting the SSH service )

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm facing this issue. i know there are so many topics regarding this. Actually I was unable to access the remote server for restarting the SSH service and removing the host key. Any help on this.

> debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>
> debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
>   ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Also I need to know the exact reason behind this.

Comment: Did you remove the host key?

Comment: remote server is not accessible. Only through SSH I'm connecting to that server. You mean host key from remote server, if yes, I was unable to remove that as remote server is not in my control.

Comment: Sorry im having trouble to understand, you have a local server under your control. And a remote server you cant access at all, the remote server is not under your control? Have you ever been able to ssh to the remote server?

Comment: Yep, the remote server is not under my control. I've been working on the remote server for the last week without any issue via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this due to my ISP's nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf`. These nameservers are often overloaded and if reverse DNS lookup fails `sshd` will drop the connection. I solved the problem by using more reliable nameservers, e.g. `8.8.8.8`